# js dictionary with key stored in variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dictionary, key, key-value

I have dictionary and a variable that stores the key. How do I access "value1"? Can myKey be evaluated before the dictionary lookup?

```
var dic = { "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2",
            "key3" : "value3"};

var myKey = "key1";

console.log(dic.myKey);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the square bracket notation `[]`

```
var dic = { "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2",
            "key3" : "value3"};

var myKey = "key1";

console.log(dic[myKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dot notation for access values, whatever you put becomes the key, so 
`dic.myKey` searches for the key "myKey".

To avoid this, you'll need to use the bracket notation. To find something using brackets, you'll have to use `dic[keyVariable]`. So in your case, you can access value1 by using `dic[myKey]`.